# Overriding NotifyIcon in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, notifyicon

I'm trying to override click events on NotifyIcons in .NET.
The problem is the class is sealed and cannot be inherited. The functionality I'd like to attain is rather than using a context menu to control the application, I'd like to doubleclick the icon to toggle the applications mode.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Just use `notifyIcon1.DoubleClick += new System.EventHandler(this.notifyIcon1_DoubleClick);`

Why you need to override it?